# applying style using styled components if two classes

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a react app and I am trying to write a css rule like the following using styled components:

```css
.react-draggable-transparent-selection .preview-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

I am trying this but it does not seem to work:

```css
const PreviewContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;

  & .react-draggable-transparent-selection {
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }
  }
`;
```

the .react-draggable-transparent-selection class and .preview-wrapper are not on the same element. How can I write this using styled components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am pretty sure that styled components do not support applying a style based on an ancestor having a conditional css class based on [this issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/330). I have opened my own github issue with styled components [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3505), but in the mean time I solved this using state in react and passing as a prop like this:

```js
const PreviewContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;

  ${({ isDragging }) => isDragging &&
    css`
      &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
      }
    `
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the element with the class `react-draggable-transparent-selection` a child of the `PreviewContainer`? Something like the below?

```
<PreviewContainer>
  ...
    <div className="react-draggable-transparent-selection">

    </div>
  ...
</PreviewContainer>
```

If it is, this is how you would style it using Styled Components:

```
const PreviewContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;

  & .react-draggable-transparent-selection {
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, No it's not. It is on an ancestor. That's actually what I meant to write in my OP but I have an extra '&'.